# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/rch Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, weblogic

Hola espero y alguien sepa ayudarme. Tengo un problema de conexion mysql con spring mvc y weblogic.

la excepción que me arroja es la siguiente.

> > Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/rch   at
> >     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)  at
> >     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
> >     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
> >       ... 56 more

Este es mi codigo de conexión Datasource.

```
   @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource rchDs() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/rch");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");

        log.info(new StringBuilder("getDataSource:").append(" ").append(dataSource));
        return dataSource;
    }
```

y mi despliege en weblogic y origen de datos esta funciónando de manera correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me falta algo por configurar. Utilizo spring mvc y mysql. Gracias.

Comment: Revisa tu achivo  si tienes agregado el conector mysql pom.xml o gradle.build de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Tu aplicación no tiene [el driver (el conector) para MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) y por eso no se puede conectar a la base de datos.

- Si usas Maven en tu proyecto, agrega la [dependencia correspondiente](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.12) en tu archivo `pom.xml`.

  ```
  <!-- dentro de la sección de dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.12</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Si no usas Maven, descarga el [conector de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) y coloca el archivo `.jar` en la carpeta `WEB-INF` del proyecto web.